# R rep function with for loop

Tags: r, function, rep

I have a year range 1981:1984. How can use  rep() function to get the following results:
For each round rep, the latest year is dropped off:  first get  1981:1984, then 1981:1983, then 1981:1982, then 1981 as shown in the table:

```
1981
1982
1983
1984
1981
1982
1983
1981
1982
1981
```

Comment: why use `rep` for this task? `unlist(sapply(1:4, function(i){1981:(1985-i)}))` would do the trick.

Comment: thank both of you. kind of magic.

Answer (score 8):

One way:

```
v = 1981:1984
v[ sequence(rev(seq_along(v))) ]
# [1] 1981 1982 1983 1984 1981 1982 1983 1981 1982 1981
```